# (NLP, TextCNN) Why in_channels equals embedding size in torch.nn.Conv1d?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, conv-neural-network

If we apply `torch.nn.Conv2d` to a "RGB" image which can be understood as 3 two-dimensional matrices, so parameter `in_channels` corresponds to the 3 channels 'R', 'G' and 'B'. And in my view, an embedded sentence whose shape is `[sentence length, embedding size]` should be considered as 1 two-dimensional matrix, so in this case, why parameter `in_channels` is not 1 but embedding size in `torch.nn.Conv1d`, not the same meaning as `torch.nn.Conv2d`?

Could you explain what's the true meaning of `in_channels` in `torch.nn.Conv1d` in nlp / TextCNN? Why it's different from `torch.nn.Conv2d`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**The embedding dimension can be considered as the in_channels in NLP while using Conv1d.**

Explanation-
Assuming that you are trying to input a sentence of length 'N' as follows -
I am a user of this ...... N.
All these words are converted to a word-embedding, say E dimensional.
This vector will be of dimension --> **[N, E]**
If you consider a batch of input sentences of batch size "B" --> **[B, N, E]**

So now you can call it as:-

```
x = nn.Conv1d(in_channels = E, out_channels = .......)
```

Take a look at- https://gist.github.com/spro/c87cc706625b8a54e604fb1024106556

Comment: Thanks for your time! Actually, I'm wondering the meaning of `in_channels` in `torch.nn.Conv1d`. Since when we use `torch.nn.Conv2d` to a 2D "RGB" image, the image can be understood as 3 two-dimensional matrices, so `in_channels` should be 3. And in my view, an embedded sentence whose shape is [sentence length, embedding size] should be considered as 1 two-dimensional matrix, so in this case why parameter `in_channels`  is not 1 but embedding size in `torch.nn.Conv1d`, not the same meaning as `torch.nn.Conv2d`? What's the true meaning of `in_channels` in `torch.nn.Conv1d`?